# Process of writing to the depth texture

Tags: opengl, shaders, vertex, depth-buffer

In openGL, let's say I output one single point from the vertex shader with this value

```
gl_Position = vec4(2.0,3.0,5.0,7.0);
```

what exact math operations happen to "z" after leaving the vertex shader?
what will be the end value of that depth texel?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8050/in-opengl-how-can-i-discover-the-depth-range-of-a-depth-buffer josh Petrie says the next operations, but he just says them and I want the exact formula

Comment: The [accepted answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/8054/24982) to the question you referenced in your comment does mention that the _z_ value is divided by _w_.

Answer (score 1):

After all of your transformations are applied (rotations, perspective transformations, etc.), all of the coordinates are divided by *w* (the fourth value in the `gl_Position` vector) to determine **Normalized Device Coordinates,** NDC. In other words NDC = *(x/w, y/w, z/w)*

The *x, y,* and *z* coordinates in NDC space are in the range [-1..1] if they are in the clip region. The *x* and *y* coordinates are used for the viewport transformation. The *z* coordinate is linearly transformed into the range [0..1] and is used for depth calculations. This last step depends on the values set by [glDepthRange](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glDepthRange.xhtml): 0=near and 1=far are the default values.

This is detailed in the OpenGL red book, and [here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html).

Comment: Are you sure about this? AFAIK, after `z/=w` z is in `-1..1` range (this is what you should get from `gl_FragCoord.z`). And *then* it is mapped to `0..1` (using something like `z = z / 2 + 0.5`), which is written to depth texture.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you are correct; I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, `z` (as well as `x` and `y`) will be divided by `w`.

Then, everything outside of `-1..1` will be culled.

And then, resulting value will be mapped to `0..1` (or to whatever range you selected with `glDepthRange()`).

In case of default range, full formula would be `depth = z / w / 2 + 0.5`.

Comment: there is something else happening after z/w

Comment: @Wusevari Edited.

Answer (score -3):

after setting

```
glDepthRange(n, f);
```

Full formula:

```
finalDepth = (gl_Position.z/gl_Position.w)*(f-n)*0.5+(f+n)*0.5
```

Bonus:
Every other answer out there about depth buffer always assumes the use of projection matrix, this matrix is a waste of space, time and precision, of the 16 floats that it has only 2 are really needed, the "field of view" and the "screen ratio".
OpenGL makes the precision worst by not giving us control of that math formula of final depth value.

Comment: The formula is correct. I would also mention that default range is `0..1`.

Comment: But the statements about projection matrix seem very  
questionable: *"waste of space"* - It's faster and easier to multiply by matrix than manually computing everything. *"makes precision worse"* - Why would manual calculations be more precise? Or if you're talking about non-linear mapping of z to depth, then there is so-called *w-buffer* to avoid this effect. | *"not giving us control of that math formula"* - Just set w to 1 and compute everything manually. Or directly assign to `gl_FragDepth`, if you only care about depth. | *"only 2 are really needed"* - You also need znear and zfar.

Comment: Don't know why the down votes, I tested the formula and finally fixed my problem, and I answer the question in this website(without links), and it has even a bonus ;^)

Comment: I think the bonus is the reason for downvotes. (At least it is for my one.)